# Adding more AND operators as needed in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So what I'm doing is having the user enter a few different tags such as `cat, dog, fish`. Then I'd

```
SELECT * FROM animals WHERE concat(' ', tags, ',') LIKE '% cat,%' AND concat (' ', tags, ',') LIKE '% dog,%';
```

for example.
Since they can enter as many tags as they want how would I add more `concat (' ', tags, ',') LIKE '% dog,%';` as needed? So if I enter 3 tags, I'd expect 3 of the `concat`'s. Any ideas on how to do this? I'm really really new and I'm not sure what to search for

Comment: Would that return an animal that's a dog, a cat and a fish at the same time?

Comment: Well its users favorite animals. I have a tag column in the user row and they can place animals they like in there, separated by a comma. Then another user can search for animals and find users that like those animals. So user A can search `dog, cat, frog` and find the user B has likes those animals @Shomz

Comment: @user302975 I suggest you put that data into a separate table.. you're going to run into problems doing it that way

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an array of animals, and you want to get all the records where the tag is any of those animals? If that's the case, this code below should work for you:

```
// sample data for the sake of the example
$tags = array("cat", "dog");

// sanitize your data (I'm assuming you're using the standard built in mysql functions)
$tags = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $tags);

// I'm assuming the field you are checking for is 'tag'?
echo sprintf("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE tag IN ('%s');", join("','", $tags));

// Outputs: SELECT * FROM animals WHERE tag IN ('cat','dog');
```

Comment: Well I have users, and they enter their favorite animals which is what I'm trying to get. So when another user searches for a user that likes `cats, dogs, fish`. They'll get a result

Comment: @bruchowski why are you using join() ??? The syntax you provided is wrong too ..The seperator should be first instead of the array

Comment: @AvinashBabu `join` is an alias for `implode`. Seems you're right about the order of parameters though, odd that it ran for me when I tested this code.. edited it anyway for correctness

Comment: @AvinashBabu apparently `join` takes parameters in either order

Comment: yeah yeah got it now ..and thanx for new info ..;)